# How do I properly parse a text file with multiple delimiters in C++?

Tags: c++, file, parsing, io, delimiter

I have to parse an input file with paragraphs into sentences. Each line in the output corresponds to a sentence. It was mostly right, but I cannot get the desired result.

The delimiters I've been asked to use were:

- .
- ."
- ?
- ?"

Test input:
The first story is about connecting the dots.

I dropped out of Reed College after the first 6 months, but then stayed around as a drop-in for another 18 months or so before I really quit. So why did I drop out?

It started before I was born. My biological mother was a young, unwed college graduate student, and she decided to put me up for adoption. She felt very strongly that I should be adopted by college graduates, so everything was all set for me to be adopted at birth by a lawyer and his wife. Except that when I popped out they decided at the last minute that they really wanted a girl. So my parents, who were on a waiting list, got a call in the middle of the night asking: "We have an unexpected baby boy; do you want him?" They said: "Of course." My biological mother later found out that my mother had never graduated from college and that my father had never graduated from high school. She refused to sign the final adoption papers. She only relented a few months later when my parents promised that I would someday go to college.

```
#include "FileIOs_WordPairs.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>



using namespace std;
bool sentenceSplitter(string& fname, vector<string>& sentences)
{
    ifstream file;
    string temp;
    size_t pos = 0;

    string token;

    file.open(fname);
    if (file.fail())
    {
        cerr << "Failed to open the file" << endl;
        return(-1);
    }

    while (getline(file, temp))
    {
        istringstream iss(temp);

        while ((pos = temp.find_first_of(".")) != string::npos)
        {
            token = temp.substr(0, pos);
            if (token.length() != 0)
                cout << token << endl;
            temp = temp.substr(pos + strlen("."));
        }

        while ((pos = temp.find_first_of("?")) != string::npos)
        {
            token = temp.substr(0, pos);
            if (token.length() != 0)
                cout << token << endl;
            temp = temp.substr(pos + strlen("?"));
        }

        while ((pos = temp.find_first_of(".\"")) != string::npos)
        {
            token = temp.substr(0, pos);
            if (token.length() != 0)
                cout << token << endl;
            temp = temp.substr(pos + strlen(".\""));
        }

        while ((pos = temp.find_first_of("?\"")) != string::npos)
        {
            token = temp.substr(0, pos);
            if (token.length() != 0)
                cout << token << endl;
            temp = temp.substr(pos + strlen("?\""));
        }
    }

}
```

Expected Output:

- The first story is about connecting the dots
- I dropped out of Reed College after the first 6 months, but then stayed around as a drop-in for another 18 months or so before I really quit
- So why did I drop out
- It started before I was born
- My biological mother was a young, unwed college graduate student, and she decided to put me up for adoption
- She felt very strongly that I should be adopted by college graduates, so everything was all set for me to be adopted at birth by a lawyer and his wife
- Except that when I popped out they decided at the last minute that they really wanted a girl
- So my parents, who were on a waiting list, got a call in the middle of the night asking: "We have an unexpected baby boy; do you want him
- They said: "Of course
- My biological mother later found out that my mother had never graduated from college and that my father had never graduated from high school
- She refused to sign the final adoption papers
- She only relented a few months later when my parents promised that I would someday go to college

Current output:

- The first story is about connecting the dots
- I dropped out of Reed College after the first 6 months, but then stayed around as a drop-in for another 18 months or so before I really quit
- So why did I drop out
- It started before I was born
- My biological mother was a young, unwed college graduate student, and she decided to put me up for adoption
- She felt very strongly that I should be adopted by college graduates, so everything was all set for me to be adopted at birth by a lawyer and his wife
- Except that when I popped out they decided at the last minute that they really wanted a girl
- So my parents, who were on a waiting list, got a call in the middle of the night asking: "We have an unexpected baby boy; do you want him?" They said: "Of course
- " My biological mother later found out that my mother had never graduated from college and that my father had never graduated from high school
- She refused to sign the final adoption papers
- She only relented a few months later when my parents promised that I would someday go to college

Simply put, I can't find a way to use ." and ?" as delimiters

Comment: Keep in mind that your while loops complete in order, so you find and output all the text up to the `.`s - even when there are `?`, `."`, or `?"` between them.  Using boost as Arash suggests is reasonable, but you could also iterate over the input character by character, copying it to the output and deciding when to inject `\n`s too.

Comment: The easiest, in this case, is probably to use a [regular expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex).

Answer (score 0):

Using boost library, it is easy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/regex.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    vector< string > results;
    std::string text = "Hi! How are you?? Today is a nice day.";
    boost::algorithm::split_regex( results, text, boost::regex( "\\!|\\.|\\?\\?" ) ) ;
    for(string sentence:results)
        std::cout << "[" << sentence << "]" << std::endl;
}
```

compile:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -lboost_regex  && ./a.out
```

result:

```
[Hi]
[ How are you]
[ Today is a nice day]
[]
```